# Positioning inner div with in parent div

Tags: html, css, positioning

Hi,

I want to create my own select box using css3 styles. I am using  1 input field and a down arrow for that.Total select box is in 1 outer div and image is in inner tag .I have to position that down arrow to right most to outer div so that it looks like select box.I am facing problem in aligning that image. I can position that tag by putting position:absolute for inner and outer tag both..If I dont put position:absolute to Outer div tag, the inner div tag is not positioned properly..(I dont know..why?).

But the problem is, if I put that, I must specify left and top for every select box(align manually).Its tough to do that if I have more that one select box in my application form.(In fact, its disgusting...)..So the inner div tag must be aligned right most to outer tag without positioning outer div tag....I hope I m clear... Please help out from this issue..

Here is my sample piece of code....

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   #Outer{ width:155px; height:20px;    *position:absolute;     border:1px solid #336633;   }
   #In{    position:absolute;   right:0px;  height:100%;    width:10px; background:red; top:0px;   }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
    <div id="Outer">
       <input type="text"/>
       <div id="In">^</div>
   </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code serves your purpose, I think.

```
<head>

    <style>

        #Outer{    

            float:left;    
            width:200px;    
            height:20px;    
            border:1px solid #336633;   
        }

        #In{    
            float:left; 
            height:100%;    
            width:10px; 
            background:red; 
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="Outer">

    <div style="float:left"><input type="text"/></div>

    <div id="In">^</div>

</div>

</body>
```

In the above code, I have added a div for your  input element and add float style in both Outer and Inner div. Another thing, your width should be more than 155px, i use it as 200px.

Please let me know whether it works or do you want anything else.

Comment: Thanks buddy,Its working fine..I have another problem,When ever I click on the arrow icon a popup will be opened which is DIV tag.It must be aligned to relative to parent div.But it is aligned to some what little bit far away from the left to parent div.This is subtle one, but I must remove that one..Can you help me out...Here is the link for that in JSFiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/ramstheroyal/LVf9P/

Comment: I resolved the prob by removing padding.But now there unnecessary gap between input box and value option popup....

Comment: What is the current output after resolving problem? Can you give me a link of jsfiddle? I can't find out the gap between input box and value option pop-up. Thanks.

Comment: It works individually fine..but problem is when I put that select box in table cell(td tag),Alignment is destroyed, image comes down and value popup gone far away...I updated it in jsfiddle ..http://jsfiddle.net/ramstheroyal/LVf9P/5/

Comment: I think it behaves differently in js fiddle,So i request you to copy that code in notepad and run it in IE(with tabele cell and without table cell),You can find the difference...Thanks

Comment: Sorry for being late. Please take a look at it : [http://jsfiddle.net/LVf9P/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/LVf9P/7/).  I have added a **div** around `input` tag and change the `width` of the parent div. Please mark my answer if it is correct.

Comment: I'm sorry of my serial doubts.I can not restrict of box width since it comes dynamically.The input field and img must share that width in the ratio of 80% and 20% respectively..Thats d prob here..One more thing is there is gap b/w select box and value help..Please check it once...Thanks

Comment: Please check it now. I have placed your propsed ratio for input and img field. [http://jsfiddle.net/LVf9P/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/LVf9P/8/). Your last problem is not understood. Please clarify me.

Comment: Thanks for your help and valuable time..Its working fine....The last statement in my previous comment is,If we click on the image a value popup is opened..right!. There is gap b/w the select box and popup..Popup must be opened immediate next to select box without any gap... I am really owe to you!Glad to talking to you..Thanks once again... Have a nice time..!!!

Comment: Thank you too. Glad to help you a bit.